# How to resolve the 'file not found' warning in R 4.3.0 when testing 'tools' examples?

Tags: r, vignette

The output of "make check" from R 4.3.0 shows a difference in the 'tools' tests that was not present in R 4.2.0.

The test in question from test/Examples/tools-ex.R is

```
library(tools)
gridEx <- system.file("doc", "grid.Rnw", package = "grid")
vi <- vignetteInfo(gridEx)
str(vi)
```

The expected output from tests/Examples/tools-Ex.Rout.save for this example is

```
List of 5
 $ file    : chr "grid.Rnw"
 $ title   : chr "Introduction to grid"
 $ depends : chr(0)
 $ keywords: chr(0)
 $ engine  : chr "utils::Sweave"
```

If the test is run on the R command line, the output is fine, but when run as part of "make check", the output file tests/Examples/tools-Ex.Rout shows a warning after the call to vignetteInfo:

```
Warning in file(con, "r") :
  file("") only supports open = "w+" and open = "w+b": using the former
```

and the output of str(vi) is:

```
List of 5
 $ file    : chr ""
 $ title   : chr ""
 $ depends : chr(0)
 $ keywords: chr(0)
 $ engine  : chr "utils::Sweave"
```

The file warning is misleading, it essentially means "file not found" -- the file grid.Rnw is not in the location expected by the test. In R 4.2.0, the source tree contains a file library/grid/doc/grid.Rnw, and in R 4.3.0, this file is now in src/library/grid/vignettes/grid.Rnw. I can resolve the error by making a link from library/grid/doc/grid.Rnw to the new location. Is this the right workaround, or should the test itself be changed?